# Laravel 5.2 using @yield and @section

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have 2 parts in my main layout: `@yield('styles')` `@yield('scripts')`

In the other template files which extended the main layout,
I use `@section('styles')` and `@section('scripts')`

When I am loading partial views, all the styles in the 'styles' sections are loading well. But, about the scripts, only the first partial view's scripts are loading and for the others, it ignores them.

Any Idea or experience before?

Comment: Let's see your code.

Comment: Have you remembered to add the @stop for the end of each @section? If so, let's see the code as Muhammet said and we can figure it out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you looked at @stack?

`@stack('css')` and `@stack('scripts')` instead of `@yeild`

you can then do

```
@push('scripts')
<script> /js/jquery.js</script>
@endpush
```

That way you can push different scripts or css to the header or footer depending on your template page

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#stacks